# Eclipse 2019-09 Connecting to Team Foundation Server Endless Loop

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

This is about Eclipse (v2019-09), Team Explorer Everywhere v14.134.0 and not Visual Studio directly.

We use both VS (.net) and Java for development and my development environment has both VS2017 and Eclipse (2019-09) installed.  VS2017 has Visual Studio Team Services set up and that is working.

My previous version of Eclipse (Oxigen) also had TS installed and it had been working.  The last time I had to do a domain Password change something got screwed up.  The eventual fix was to revert my password back to the previous and everything has been fine till I had to restart Eclipse.  Now I just keep getting stuck in a loop trying to connect.

[image]

[a]

- I click next
- I click on the link taking me to where I enter the code
- I select my account
- I am told I am now logged on and I can close the window
- I go back click the Okay button and goto [a]

I have tried clearing out browser history, resetting credentials, adding a line into the .ini file, most of these solutions are years old.

Research:
I have trolled through various sites looking for solutions, even here on stack.  Developer websites, deactivated forums, so the grading is incorrect, I have spent the good part of day looking for answers and trying various attacks including uninstalling and installing Eclipse and the latest plugin.

There is no indication that anything is wrong with my AzureOps Dev account (that I can tell) yet I get no error message in any log file I can file (Events, eclipse)

This should not be worse than rocket science and not only have I wasted a day, I cannot sync local code with our Team Server so others can get latest version.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

....And yes, I uninstalled Eclipse and now have a new version.

What am I missing or where can I look for answers.

Comment: Are you able to use Visual Studio to login  TFS server ? Have you tired  clear TFS cache: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/

Comment: Yes, I can login into TFS via Visual Studio.  I looked at the link and not sure how that would impact my eclipse IDE.  Is there something similar for reading the link, before taking a drastic action, I am wondering if the plugin is using a different path for verification.  The documentation on the plugin is light.

Comment: Is there a log file or trace file that can shed light on what is going on.  I tested putting bad credentials in and it gave me a correct error.  I put correct credentials in and got the code and tested a bad account or password and got proper responses.  I put everything in correct, click okay and the screen just repeats.

Comment: Hi j.hull we don't have a auto-generated trace log. But we usually manually capture a decrypted Fiddler Trace file for further investigation. Besides, since StackOverflow it's a open community. If you want MSFT help you tracking the detail info in trace log, we usually suggest you submit a ticket in MSFT own [developercommunity site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), it has a private mode to protect your personal privacy.

Answer (score 0):

There are still questions regarding how to trace certification process with the Plug-in, but I have solved the immediate problem.

There were two accounts in Microsoft developer (DevOps), a work related account and a personal account.  **Both** were set up under the same business email address, let's say

forgetful@business.com

I would use the business credentials in the add existing team project window to select a TFS.  When I then click on the link and a browser window is opened where I am to place the "code", I would choose the business account.  Nothing would be said that I choose the wrong account, but when I get back to Eclipse and the Add window, rinse and repeat.

Just by accident I tried to access, in the website, something using my business account and I was told I was using the wrong account.  I logged into DevOps with the personal (remember, same email address), and just for the hell of it, tried connecting to TFS.

**It Work**

Somehow the plug in is aware of my AD credentials for local access to TFS (which is the case for VS), but when I switch over to the Microsoft website, the plugin seems to not recognize the business, but the personal.

Two issues that bother me is that I cannot figure how to switch it over to my business account and why there is no better error messaging when it does not connect.

For anyone who may have similar issues (login looping), check to see if you have two accounts in Microsoft under the same email address and try both.  Also, manually log into the DevOps site before trying the connection.

I'll consider this closed.

Comment: Hi j.hull, appreciate your sharing. You could mark it as an answer. In case any others get into same situation.